# Prevent AOP(AspectJ) code to be triggered while running test

Tags: spring-boot, testing, aspectj, spring-aop

In my spring boot project, I am using [MockMVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) to test controller(web) layer. But I also have AOP(AspectJ) logic in my project, when I run unit test for controller with MockMVC, the test also triggers AOP code, how can I prevent AOP code to be triggered while running unit test for controller?

```
@Test
public void testMyControllerMethod() {
   ...

   // myRequest hits an endpoint function of my controller, there is also AOP intercept the function call, how can I disable AOP to be triggered while running test?
   mockMVC.perform(myRequest).andExpect(okStatus)

}
```

Question is in my code comment :)

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433658/disabling-certain-aspects-during-unit-test-runs), I understand to use the `if()` expression, but I don't get `TestMode.ACTIVE`, there is no such thing in Spring boot. If someone could let me know how to check whether code is running unit test or not at runtime, I would know how to prevent AOP logic run as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling certain aspects during unit test runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433658/disabling-certain-aspects-during-unit-test-runs)

Comment: Yes, but the answer doesn't work for me, e.g. how can I know the code is running under test mode? That answer mentioned `TestMode.ACTIVE`, I don't know where that comes from, there is no TestMode class in spring boot.

Comment: That's a global variable that you set in the tests. The aspects have to check for this variable. It's a manual solution not something that comes from Spring

Comment: Could you please provide a simple skeleton example of that glable variable? Where to put it and where to update the value?

Comment: public final boolean TestMode.ACTIVE = false; And in the test you set TestMode.ACTIVE = true;

Comment: Thanks, I got another issue related with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418907/pointcut-expression-if-contains-unsupported-pointcut-primitive-if

Answer (score 0):

What I meant in the other answer, as Simon already tried to explain to you, is something like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class TestMode {
  public static boolean ACTIVE = false;
}
```

But actually there I also listed a few other options such as environment variables and system properties. If I were you I would use one of those because in your Maven or Gradle build it would be very easy to set properties or environment variables via configuration. Your `if()` pointcut could access those variables.

---

Especially in the context of Spring there is an even simpler option: a test application configuration. Just provide a configuration without aspects to your tests. That way you can have different configurations for

- production environment,
- unit tests (no aspects),
- integration tests (e.g. with aspects but different from unit test and production).
- et cetera.

The advantage here is that you don't need any `if()` pointcuts or build any other knowledge about test/production environments into your aspects, which is quite ugly. My other answer only shows what you ***can*** do, it does not say it is the best solution.