# Pointcut expression 'if()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'if'

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using AspectJ in my Spring boot project for AOP.

I have declared a [if()](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697) point cut:

```
public class myPointCuts {
   // a global boolean variable, value can be updated at runtime.
   public static boolean IS_RESULT_FINE;

   @Pointcut("if()")
    public static boolean isResultFine() {
            return IS_RESULT_FINE;
    }
}
```

At compile time, I get error:

```
Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'if()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'if'
```

My declared dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.1.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.4'
```

What is wrong with my `if()` point cut expression ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to use `if()` in Spring AOP, but as the error message *"unsupported pointcut primitive 'if'"* implies, `if()` is not available in Spring AOP, only in AspectJ, which is also explained in the corresponding [Spring manual section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). You find a positive and negative list there.

If you want to use `if()` you do need to switch to [AspectJ with load-time weaving](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). But I am not sure it is worth switching the AOP framework for the sake of the `if()` pointcut which is not much more than syntactic sugar for an `if (IS_RESULT_FINE)` statement you could also just put right into your advice method.